# Filtering files in documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im currently searching my documents folder for .png images using

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];
    fileList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *filename in dirContents) {
        NSString *fileExt = [filename pathExtension];
        if ([fileExt isEqualToString:@"png"]) {

            [fileList addObject:filename];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"document folder content list %@ ",fileList);
```

Id like to make the search more specific, ie search for images named `lorry.png`, or `car.png` for example (for brevity) rathe rthan getting everything with .png

My image files are named by apending a reference number `self.certificate.reference` to the png so I get something like `car283TYZ.png`.  This way I can utilise the correct image for the certificate that created it.

What ive tried

```
//search folder
    NSString *certRefstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.certificate.reference];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];
    fileList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *filename in dirContents) {
        NSString *fileExt = [filename pathExtension];

        if ([fileExt isEqualToString:@"png"]&&[certRefstring rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.certificate.reference]].location == NSNotFound) {

            NSLog(@"string does not contain cert ref %@, file list is %@",self.certificate.reference,fileList);


        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"string contains cert ref %@ and png files %@",self.certificate.reference,fileList);

            [fileList addObject:filename];

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"document folder content list %@ ",fileList);
```

This seemed to return everything in the folder. So im looking for a solution for searching more specifically/iterating over my .png files in my documents folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have nested 'if's

```
if ([fileExt isEqualToString:@"png"])
{
    if ([certRefstring rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.certificate.reference]].location == NSNotFound)
    {    
        NSLog(@"string does not contain cert ref %@, file list is %@",self.certificate.reference,fileList);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"string contains cert ref %@ and png files %@",self.certificate.reference,fileList);
        [fileList addObject:filename];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *certRefstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.certificate.reference];
```

so

```
[certRefstring rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.certificate.reference]].location == NSNotFound
```

is always NO. There is a reason why you receive everything.
Probably it should be changed to

```
[filename rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.certificate.reference]].location == NSNotFound
```

Comment: Your right, made all the difference searching `fileName`, combined with Merlevde answer it sorted it.  Thanks, plus 1 for you!